# Getting IllegalStateException in my program?

Tags: java, while-loop, exception, illegalstateexception

[Stacktrace Here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/OXdmT.png)

import java.util.*;

public class AccountClient {

```
public static void main(String[] args)  {
    Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);
    boolean infiniteLoop = true;
    boolean invalidInput;
    int id;
    // Create array of different accounts
    Account[] accountArray = new Account[10];
    //Initialize each account array with its own unique id and a starting account balance of $100
    for (int i = 0; i < accountArray.length; i++) {
        accountArray[i] = new Account(i, 100);
    }
    do {    
        try {       
            //inner loop to detect invalid Input
            do {
                invalidInput = false;
                System.out.print("Enter an id: ");
                id = input.nextInt(); 
                if (id < 0 || id > 9) {
                    System.out.println("Try again. Id not registered in system. Please enter an id between 0 and 9 (inclusive).");
                    invalidInput = true;
                    input.nextLine();
                }           
            } while (invalidInput);
            boolean exit;
            do {
                exit = false;
                boolean notAnOption;
                int choice;
                do {
                    notAnOption = false;
                    System.out.print("\nMain Menu\n1: check balance\n2: withdraw\n3: deposit\n4: exit\nEnter a choice: ");
                    choice = input.nextInt();
                    if (choice < 1 || choice > 4) {
                        System.out.println("Sorry, " + choice + " is not an option. Please try again and enter a number between 1 and 4 (inclusive).");
                        notAnOption = true;
                    }
                } while(notAnOption);
                switch (choice) {
                case 1: System.out.println("The balance for your account is $" + accountArray[id].getBalance());
                    break;
                case 2: {
                    boolean withdrawFlag;
                    do {
                        System.out.print("Enter the amount you would like to withdraw: ");
                        double withdrawAmount = input.nextInt();
                        if (withdrawAmount > accountArray[id].getBalance()) {
                            System.out.println("Sorry, you only have an account balance of $" + accountArray[id].getBalance() + ". Please try again and enter a number at or below this amount.");
                            withdrawFlag = true;
                        }
                        else {
                            accountArray[id].withdraw(withdrawAmount);
                            System.out.println("Thank you. Your withdraw has been completed.");
                            withdrawFlag = false;
                        }
                    } while (withdrawFlag);
                }

                    break;
                case 3: {
                    System.out.print("Enter the amount you would like to deposit: ");
                    double depositAmount = input.nextInt();
                    accountArray[id].deposit(depositAmount);
                    System.out.println("Thank you. You have successfully deposited $" + depositAmount + " into your account.");
                    }
                    break;
                case 4: {
                    System.out.println("returning to the login screen...\n");
                    exit = true;
                    }
                    break;
                }

            } while (exit == false);

        }

        catch (InputMismatchException ex) {
            System.out.println("Sorry, invalid input. Please enter a number, no letters or symbols.");
        }
        finally {
            input.close();          
            }

        } while (infiniteLoop);
    } 


}
```

The exception code:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.IllegalStateException: Scanner closed
    at java.util.Scanner.ensureOpen(Scanner.java:1070)
    at java.util.Scanner.next(Scanner.java:1465)
    at java.util.Scanner.nextInt(Scanner.java:2117)
    at java.util.Scanner.nextInt(Scanner.java:2076)
    at playground.test.main.Main.main(Main.java:47)
```

Hello, I made a basic program that uses a class called account to simulate an ATM machine. I wanted to throw an exception if the user didn't type in a letter. This worked fine, however I needed to make it loop so the program didn't terminate after it threw the exception. To do this I just put the try catch in the do while loop I had previously. When I did this though, it's throwing an IllegalStateException every time I type in a letter or choose to exit an inner loop I have which takes the user back to the loop of asking them to enter their id. What is an IllegalStateException, what is causing it in my case, and how would I fix this? Thanks.

Comment: Post the _whole_ stacktrace and tell us the line where the error occurs!

Comment: Enter an id: 0

Main Menu
1: check balance
2: withdraw
3: deposit
4: exit
Enter a choice: 4
returning to the login screen...

Exception in thread "main" Enter an id: java.lang.IllegalStateException: Scanner closed
 at java.util.Scanner.ensureOpen(Unknown Source)
 at java.util.Scanner.next(Unknown Source)
 at java.util.Scanner.nextInt(Unknown Source)
 at java.util.Scanner.nextInt(Unknown Source)
 at AccountClient.main(AccountClient.java:23)

Comment: Don't post that as a comment but edit your question!

Comment: This is actually my first post so I'm sorry for the horrible formatting. Is there a certain way for me to post the stacktrace or do i just copy and paste it with my code.

Comment: Don't close the scanner.

Answer (score 3):

It's fairly simple, after you catch the exception the [`finally`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/exceptions/finally.html) clause gets executed. Unfortunately you're closing the scanner within this clause and [`Scanner.close()`](http://grepcode.com/file/repository.grepcode.com/java/root/jdk/openjdk/8u40-b25/java/util/Scanner.java#Scanner.close%28%29) closes the underlying input stream (`System.in` in this case).

The standard input stream `System.in` once closed can't be opened again.

To fix this you have to omit the finally clause and close the scanner when your program needs to terminate and not earlier.

Comment: You even mention that closing a `Scanner` close the `InputStream`. Perfect !